# How to fix the display "Not Accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine" on DataStudio Report using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am using a Scorecard in Google Data Studio, and I keep having this warning (Thunder) ⚠️ sign saying  - "Not Accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine". Is this an error, and how do you fix it?

Comment: Having the same issue. If I (via the BigQuery connector) choose a table under "My Projects", I can get it accelleration no problem. But if I go to "Custom Query" (under the same connector), and query the same table, I get the above warning that data isn't accellerated. I would be confused if custom queries weren't supported.

Answer (score 6):

To hide this "Not Accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine" message,

1. Open the report in Edit mode, and click on the label/Scorecard.
2. On the panel on the right side of the page, click on STYLE.
3. Scroll down to Chart Header and select "Do not show".

The Lightning icon disappears, as as the message.

*You may up-vote this answer if it is helpful.*

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error, just a warning to let you know that you can enable the BI Engine.

In order to enable the BI Engine you just need to [create your BI Engine reservation](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/getting-started-data-studio#step_three_create_your_reservation) by going to your BigQuery Admin Console.

Please keep in mind that this can generate new charges to your account.

Comment: Do you know if custom queries can be accellerated, assuming you are querying a table?

Comment: I have the Bi Engine Reservation set up. I am still getting this error "Not accelerated by BigQuery BI Engine This data source connects to a BigQuery view. Support for views and SQL is limited at this time." I am using views in BigQuery for row level access.

Comment: I have not found any information if BigQuery BI Engine does not support Views AT ALL. Or "fixing" something on Big Query end will fix it.